# List into csv and csv into list

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

I have this list:

```py
[Header, 132, mail@wurst, [adasdsd, 1, 3, 4], [sdsdsd, 12, 3, 4], [sdsds, 3, 3]]
```

and want to save it as a csv file and import it after transfer via ftp as the same list.
I want:

```py
[Header, 132, mail@wurst, [adasdsd, 1, 3, 4], [sdsdsd, 12, 3, 4], [sdsds, 3, 3]]
```

But i cant find a way to have the same list structure after importing the list.
whatever solution from stackoverflow i use it always changes the structure of my list after import.

NO Solutions with:

- Pandas
- Numpy
- changes on list

Only Solutions using either:

- without import
- csv writer

Comment: Is there any reason to specifically use csv as format? Using pickle or json would carry type-information, making this way easier

Comment: Thanks for your Advice. CSV is not negotiable at the moment.

Comment: Could you please show me the output you want as csv

Comment: i want to  read the csv file a way, i have exact the same list i did write into it.

Comment: You want the first group *not* in a sub-list, but all following groups in a sub-list?

Comment: objects mentioned liked Header, mail@wurst or adasdsd shouldn't they be quoted or they are objects which contains some value?

Comment: they are strings.

Comment: yes the first ones cant end up in a sub list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the header length (3 in this case) you can hardcode it in. Otherwise you will have to do something really tacky, or deal with the header like every other record.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv
listing = [
        'Header', 132, 'mail@wurst',
        ['adasdsd', 1, 3, 4],
        ['sdsdsd', 12, 3, 4],
        ['sdsds', 3, 3]
]
with open('listing.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    csvout = csv.writer(outfile)
    csvout.writerow(listing[:3])
    csvout.writerows(listing[3:])
with open('listing.csv') as infile:
    csvin = csv.reader(infile)
    header = next(csvin)
    listing = [row for row in csvin]
    print(header + listing)
```

[Added later...]
Of course, if the CSV file already exists, no hardcoding need be done. Read the file first, and you already have the header separated out from the remainder.

Comment: Your Solution does Work for me. As it aint is what i asked for, and maybe someone else has the same Problem maybe it would be great to have a slightly more explicit explanation about the code ( commenting on code) and a easy to understand reason why not to do what i did try to do. As it is fine for me i will accept your Answer as a Solution. Thanks for your Help

Comment: `next(iterable)` fetches, as implied, the next element of the iterable and advances the pointer to the following. `[row for row in csvin]` is a "list comprehension" that makes a list of lists of the remaining lines of the spreadsheet. A big reason why *not* to do it this way is, it's unnecessarily complicated. A csv file maps easily to a list of lists, and back again, and there would have to be a really good reason to want the header treated specially.

Glad to help, and thank you for accepting my answer.